# JSoup Login and Cookie

Tags: java, cookies, html-parsing, jsoup

I'm trying to login into a site using JSoup but I'm having trouble getting a good cookie back.

I'm not sure if the URL or login data is incorrect. Any help would be much appreciated.

The login page is [here](https://go.sfu.ca/psp/goprd/?cmd=login&errorPg=err&languageCd=ENG)

I'm currently trying with the following code:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://go.sfu.ca/psp/goprd/?cmd=login&languageCd=ENG")
                    .data("user", "myUserID", "pwd", "myPassword")
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .execute();
```

I do not get the same amount of cookie information if I were 
to login in a browser and cannot request the pages that are required for you to be logged in.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! 
Thanks.

Comment: so what do you get back? actualy the request has 2 more parameters. userid and Submit. include those 2. if it still doesn't work include the headers.

Comment: ahh, I was missing the Submit parameter, now I get a good cookie back. Thanks!

Comment: If you've found a solution, please post an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the Login parameter in the form. After including that I was able to get a good cookie back.