# Curl retrieve JSON data from HTTPS

Tags: json, ajax, curl

I am trying to retrieve data from one site to be able to apply some models on them. And although, I was able to login with [jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846493/jsoup-login-with-form-post). It didn't get the content because it was loaded as JSON through AJAX.

Using firefox (Ubuntu) i got this curl after inspecting the xhr:

> curl
>   'https://target.helpshift.com/xhr/view/issue-details/?publish_id=540672&viewing=1'
>   -H 'Host: target.helpshift.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0' -H
>   'Accept:
>   text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' -H
>   'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'X-Requested-With:
>   XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Referer:
>   https://target.helpshift.com/admin/issue/540672/' -H 'Cookie:
>   _ga=GA1.3.1855716730.1445436566;
>   _csrf_token=4mMuJX5jieMAdq_WN1elKiBh0415w-0TDxN_R6kx6SQ; _dc_gtm_UA-33692972-1=1; __hs=zHb6Mr4Ds9mIaFuKbWXE9XDkDkuSzSGmmz9PgRmtmKR4Dnu1fZM4BXqys%2Bw%2FSF6cDvLv%2FCUrrG4alZsYZtMx57Qe4RU8aKKCIM6%2FSKY0PyRp8zJPJsZug7Ec1x%2F2o%2BbgGkOhqi0vi4G7Z2tYxPBAyrdJJNSjszJS6GgTTB051uMbaoSJLyQww11EKn0yU3W4uzjfmTsf%2BHo30bj6hjOdlRKY68dSVXGHIA31jZNAM%3D--3Z

However, when running with curl directly in the terminal, I get:

**curl: (6) Could not resolve host: target.helpshift.com**

If, I edit and resend through firefox it works. But it won't be practical to run that on each of the 10000 pages I am researching.

How can I get this json through curl?  maybe the problem is https?!
Can I make Firefox send those calls without editing it one by one?

**EDIT:**

- I am able to ping `target.helpshift.com` from the terminal without proxy
- removing  `-H 'Host: target.helpshift.com'` didn´t change the result

Comment: No, the problem is not HTTPS – it’s that cURL can’t resolve the host name to an IP address.

Comment: Does Firefox use a proxy ? If yes configure the same for curl. Are you able to ping that host ?

Comment: Why are you passing a `Host` header?  That exact host name is already in the URL.  Have you tried it without this header?

Comment: @JimmyJames I just copied from the firefox inspecting network option. I thought that was the best way try curl was to use that (since it was generated by firefox who was being able to send those ajax requests)

Comment: Try without it and see if you can ping the host as Marged suggested.

Comment: @Marged see the udpated question.

Comment: Have you tried forcing ipv4 by adding -4 ? What is the result when run with -v ?

Comment: @Marged thanks, I cannot believe that the problem was that simple.

Comment: I found the solution by searching on stack overflow ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CURL and HTTPS, "Cannot resolve host"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341644/curl-and-https-cannot-resolve-host)